# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController not showing birthdays

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm want to use ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to allow the user to pick a contact and add their info to my app. It's very important that the birthday property works, however that seems to be the only thing I can't get to work. Right now I am using the code straight from apples example app. The user hits a button and it runs this:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
// Display only a person's phone, email, and birthdate
NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty],
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty],
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonBirthdayProperty], nil];


picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;
// Show the picker
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The picker loads fine and all the contacts show up, but when I click them, no birthdays will display. I've tested lots of kABPerson properties (including the other date property) and they all work, except for kABPersonAlternateBirthdayProperty which crashes the app. Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: I've also experienced the same problem with iOS 8. Birthdays are not showing up despite adding kABPersonBirthdayProperty to the displayedItems